# javascript Window.onscroll to move a div vertically

Tags: javascript, onscroll

I have a simple script:
I want to move vertically my div when the page scrolls, but although the event is fired the div remains in the same position

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onscroll = DoScroll;
    function DoScroll() {
        var mydiv = document.getElementById("myFloatingDiv");
        mydiv.top = mydiv.top + 230;             
    }
</script>  

<style>
    body {
        background-color: linen;
        margin-left: 50px;
        margin-right:60px;
        margin-top:15px;
    }

    .myFloatingDivCSS{
        position:absolute;
        left:50px;
        top:100px;
        width:20%;
        height:300px;
        background:blue;
    }
</style> 

<body>
    <div class="myFloatingDivCSS" id="myFloatingDiv" ">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

But I do not see the div moving...Why is that happening?

Comment: Is it `mydiv.style.top = parseInt(mydiv.style.top) + 230 + 'px';`?

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style to learn how to get/set an elements style.

Comment: When I write:if(mydiv.top = mydiv.style.top){
     alert("ok");}
I do not get any alert..

Comment: What test can I write to see if the top has been changing or not? I do not see any change visually, but maybe there is some constrain that brings the top back?

Comment: Your div has an extra `"` at the end of the line that you should remove. I don't know if it's related to your problem, though :-)

Comment: `mydiv.top` can show an `error` in the `console`. Have you tried what I showed. Do it.

Comment: hollsk I have removed that, but it did not solve the issue

Comment: I tried this:
function DoScroll() {
  var mydiv = document.getElementById("myFloatingDiv");
    
  if(mydiv){
     alert("ok");}
  }

and I got the alert

Comment: Ajax I tried what you wrote but nothing

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer that I wanted, thanks to all that have written here:

```
window.onscroll = DoScroll;


function DoScroll() {
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("myFloatingDiv");
    mydiv.style.top = Math.max(100, window.pageYOffset) + 'px';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for DoScroll

```
  window.onwheel= DoScroll;
  function DoScroll(e) {
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("myFloatingDiv");
    var top = window.getComputedStyle(mydiv).top;
    var delta = e.wheelDelta > 0 ? 230 : -230;
    mydiv.style.top = parseInt(top) + delta + 'px';
  }
```

or this

```
  window.onscroll = DoScroll;
  function DoScroll() {
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("myFloatingDiv");
    mydiv.style.top = -window.pageYOffset + 230 + 'px';
  }
```

Comment: yes that did it! But now I can I move it up and down according to the scrolling?

Comment: change the event to `onwheel` and grab the wheelDelta to get the direction

Comment: also changing myFloatingDiv to `position:fixed` might be helpful

Comment: But what if the user uses the scrollbar and not the mouse wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Here other approach:

```
function DoScroll() {
  var mydiv = document.getElementById("myFloatingDiv");
  mydiv.style.top = mydiv.offsetTop + 230 + 'px';
}
```

Comment: I would like the div to move according to the page scroll amount. 230px was only an example, because I wanted a way to see that it was moving.